# расположение элементов

Tags: html, jquery, css, вёрстка

реализовывала галерею с миниатюрами с помощью lightGallery, расположение как на картинке, по клику на миниатюре изображения увеличиваются и все срабатывает, а как сделать тоже самое на большое изображение, я пока в тупике. Может вообще все не так делаю

```
<div class="container-gallery" >
       <div class="static-img">
            <img src="http:....>
        </div>
        <div class="dynamic-img" style="margin-top:0%">
            <ul id="lightgalery" class="gallery">
                 <li data-src="https:...>
                  <a href="#">
                     <img src="https:....">
                  </a>
                 </li>

                 <li data-src="https:....">
                  <a href="#">
                     <img src="https:...">
                  </a>
                 </li>
```

стили:

```
 .container-gallery{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        border: 2px solid red;
    }
    .gallery{
        display: flex;
    }
    .gallery ul {
     list-style: none outside none;
     padding-left: 0;
      }
      .gallery li {
     height: 100px;
     margin-bottom: 6px;
     margin-right: 6px;
     width: 100px;
      }
      .gallery li a {
     height: 100px;
     width: 100px;
      }
      .gallery li a img {
     max-width: 100px;
      }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да, разметка отличается, так как я не знала, как список сделать на двух строках, чтобы на первой была одна картинка, а на второй 3

Answer (score 0):

С утра с новыми мыслями, разобралась! :) 
Сделала все картинки списком, добавила верхней картинке класс first-image и прописала стили:

```
.gallery li:nth-child(1) {
float: none;
height: auto;
width: 100%;

  }
.gallery .first-image {
max-width: 250px;
margin-left:30px;
margin-top: -30px;
  }
```